# How to sign in with the Google+ API using Django?

Tags: django, oauth, google-api

How might I go about adding a Google+ API sign-in to my Django website?

Comment: How to do sign-out using Google oauth in python?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

First you must create OAuth credentials for Google+.

1. Go to the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. Create a new project.
3. Go to "APIs and authentication" -> "Authorization screen" and give your product a name. Click "Save".
4. Go to "APIs and authentication" -> "Credentials". Under "OAuth", click "Create New Client ID". Add "http://localhost:8000/soc/complete/google-oauth2/" should be listed as a callback URL. This will only work for testing, make sure to put in your actual domain when in production.

Now let's add `python-social-auth` to your Django app.

1. Install `python-social-auth` with `pip`
2. Set the appropriate Django settings:

   - Add `'social.apps.django_app.default'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`:
   - Add the `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET` settings with the client key and secret you created earlier. The client key is the "Client ID" listed in the "Credentials" screen in the Google developer console, the one which ends in ".apps.googleusercontent.com". Only take the part before the dot. The secret is listed as "Client secret".
   - Make sure you have the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting explicitly defined, and that it contains `'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2'`. An example would be:

     ```
     AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
         'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
         'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
     ```
   - Define the `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` setting as detailed in [the python-social-auth documentation](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html#authentication-pipeline). What every setting does is listed in that page.

   If you have something to do with the information you get from Google+, I recommend defining a function:

   ```
       def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
           if backend.name == "google-oauth2":
              # do something
   ```

   where `user` is a `django.contrib.auth.models.User` object, and `response` is a dictionary. Then add that function to the `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` using the full module path, after `create_user`.

   If you don't want to do anything with that information you can leave the default pipeline as-is.

Finally, you'll want to add the `python-social-auth` urls to your site's `urlpatterns`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include 
url("^soc/", include("social.apps.django_app.urls", namespace="social"))
```

And that should do it! It's time for testing. First, `./manage.py makemigrations` for the required migrations of `python-social-auth`, and then `./manage.py migrate`, as explained [here](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/django.html#database). Then, you can run the development server, and go to http://localhost:8000/soc/login/google-oauth2/?next=/ .

Hopefully I did not skip explaining any step and it will work. Feel free to ask more questions and [read the docs](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org). Also, here is a [working example](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/tree/master/examples/django_example) that you should check out.

Comment: i have followed all steps, its working as the user login using social auth but my user is not getting created , its just login , though i see a new record is created in table "social_auth_usersocialauth" but the no new user is created in User table. i am extending the AbstractBaseUser and created my custom user domain. any help would be appreciated

Comment: I wish I could up vote this answer many times... I've read 3 tutorials and only after reading this I got it working.

Comment: Also make sure to add the Google+ API to the list of enabled APIs on the Google Developer Console (under APIs), otherwise you'll get a 403

Comment: Where does `include` come from? In a fresh Django + DRF + social-auth, that is not a predefined function, and `manage.py` runs crash when they hit it.

Comment: `include` comes from `django.conf.urls`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/

Comment: Note that at some point after this answer was posted `python-social-auth` was changed over to a new library structure; it is now `social-auth-core`, with dedicated apps for specific frameworks, so in this case `social-auth-app-django`.

Comment: How to do sign-out using Google oauth in python?

Comment: This works for the GoogleOAuth2, but not for GooglePlusAuth backend.

Comment: I am getting AuthFailureError, I am calling this:
http://<my_url>/soc/login/google-oauth2/?next=/ 

I used POST and GET methods (With GET I am getting 302)

Comment: In the browser I am getting this

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, http://<my_url>/auth/complete/google-oauth2/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/...

Comment: Some new notice. In `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` should be `social_core` instead of `social`

Answer (score 43):

[@rhaps0dy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4521118/rhaps0dy)'s answer is correct, but `python-social-auth` is now deprecated and migrated as `social-auth-app-django`. So this is what I made different from [@rhaps0dy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4521118/rhaps0dy) guidelines.

1. Instead of `python-social-auth`, I installed `social-auth-app-django`,
2. `'social.apps.django_app.default'` becomes `'social_django'`
3. `'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2'` is now `'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2'`
4. `url("^soc/", include("social.apps.django_app.urls", namespace="social"))` becomes `url("^soc/", include("social_django.urls", namespace="social"))`

Comment: thanks for sharing, with the previous values it crashed everywhere

Comment: Thank you both! Pretty clean answer and it's working with modifications mentioned by georgi

Comment: Thanks very much! It really helps me a lot!