# django social authentication error using python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I am following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058520/how-to-sign-in-with-the-google-api-using-django) which is very clear and helpful, i have configured all the settings, but after login using gmail when i am redirected to [localhost:8000/soc/complete/google-oauth2/?state=jAwzw...](http://ocalhost:8000/soc/complete/google-oauth2/?state=jAwzw)
. I am getting this error

```
HTTPError at /soc/complete/google-oauth2/
403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=ya29..wwKoNcTfjGshqc8UYfdziBbgVtYP4bgBZ9ehrfsHJjfs-v6Cy2X3ULsdh_rJwbfApw&alt=json
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/soc/complete/google-oauth2/?state=jAwzw3EhdvFdUCv2DFia8fN4n7tUic6u&code=4/nvOb3r-U-ZXrxFCT1dSKcTE2wR8MbxhonRWX60cP4-0&authuser=0&session_state=e8244f9ad9dec2b21c83e2b153a6e9595ccefac4..e292&prompt=consent
Django Version: 1.8.1
Exception Type: HTTPError
Exception Value:    
403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=ya29..wwKoNcTfjGshqc8UYfdziBbgVtYP4bgBZ9ehrfsHJjfs-v6Cy2X3ULsdh_rJwbfApw&alt=json
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py in raise_for_status, line 840
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/aditya/django/myapp/socialapp',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Wed, 13 Apr 2016 11:33:21 +0000
```

I am not sure about the **SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE** settings, i have just copied them , which are like

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

Can you please explain whats the issue and how exactly this **SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE** works ?

Comment: Did you activate the Google+ API on google api console?

Comment: It worked, what a miss , thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ddalu5 can u help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36598489/user-not-created-by-logging-in-through-google-using-python-social-auth, please

Comment: I'm on it, don't forget to mark this issue as resolved

Answer (score 18):

The issue is resolved , Just enabled the Google+ API , thanks [@ddalu5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104861/ddalu5)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

For all those people that have the same issue, one alternative to solve it is to update the package. I have the problem in v1 and enabling Google+ doesn't solve it, but upgrading to v4 does.