# Google OAuth with Django

Tags: python, django, git, oauth, google-api

I am following [How to sign in with the Google+ API using Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058520/how-to-sign-in-with-the-google-api-using-django/29096487#29096487) to use Google Sign In for my Django app. I am on the step that says

> Add the SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY and SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET settings with the client key and secret you created earlier.

I am wary of adding these directly to `settings.py` because they will then be committed to my git repo. How can I make these values available in my app without exposing them unnecessarily?

I think environment variables are common for this purpose. I also see that I can download a JSON file from my Google Developer Console.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned here](http://fearofcode.github.io/blog/2013/01/15/how-to-scrub-sensitive-information-from-django-settings-dot-py-files/), the idea is to only version a template for `settings.py`, not the actual file (with its secret values)

I prefer for that using a [content filter driver as I describe here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48449663/6309).
That would generate automatically your `settings.py` with the correct values on `git checkout`.
And you need to do is then figure out from *where* you want to fetch those sensitive values. For instance, an [online Hashicorp Vault](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/vault/).